# query for finding average of average stored in mongodb using count of every average

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, average

We have data like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64326493749326499446"),
    "dId" : "d_155",
    "pId" : "5f4cb595cff47e0001b20882",
    "sId" : "825",
    "paramName" : "Utility_Air_Flow",
 "avg" : 488270.454545455,
            "count" : NumberLong(220),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-03T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "dataPerHour" : {
        "19" : {
            "min" : 8399.0,
            "max" : 995990.0,
            "avg" : 488270.454545455,
            "count" : NumberLong(220),
            "values" : [ 
                {
                    "paramValue" : "90235",
                    "time" : ISODate("2020-09-04T13:37:07.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "paramValue" : "272297",
                    "time" : ISODate("2020-09-04T13:37:14.000Z")
                }
            ]
        },
        "20" : {
            "min" : 8399.0,
            "max" : 995990.0,
            "avg" : 488270.454545455,
            "count" : NumberLong(220),
            "values" : [ 
                {
                    "paramValue" : "90235",
                    "time" : ISODate("2020-09-04T13:37:07.000Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "paramValue" : "272297",
                    "time" : ISODate("2020-09-04T13:37:14.000Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_class" : "org.nec.iotplatform.entities.RawData"
}
```

and we need to find average of all the average of already stored averages inside dataPerHour.

We need to find average of averages according to the formulae:

> (average1*count1)+(avarege2*count2)+
> (average3*count3)/(count1+count2+count3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      dataPerHour: {
        $objectToArray: "$dataPerHour"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "average": {
        "$divide": [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$dataPerHour",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                "$add": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "$multiply": [
                      "$$this.v.count",
                      "$$this.v.avg"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$dataPerHour",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                "$add": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.v.count"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HJVjeywXnmc)

Comment: Thank you so much ......I also need to calculate average of average lying at line no 7 using the same formulae

Comment: don't include ......only use line no7 average and count for calculation  .....assume having  multiple json in database

Comment: @PRAMODKUMAR Did you mean that you have to include the average lying at line no 7 and count along with the ones in dataPerHour using the same formulae? Then see the updated query:    https://mongoplayground.net/p/R4-EsH3AKQu

Comment: "_id" : ObjectId("64326493749326499446"),
    "dId" : "d_155",
    "pId" : "5f4cb595cff47e0001b20882",
    "sId" : "825",
    "paramName" : "Utility_Air_Flow",
 "avg" : 488270.454545455,
            "count" : NumberLong(220),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-03T18:30:00.000Z"),

Comment: Only use above data

Comment: [{
  "dId": "d_155",
  "pId": "5f4cb595cff47e0001b20882",
  "sId": "825",
  "paramName": "Utility_Air_Flow",
  "avg": 488270.454545455,
  "count": 220
 },
 {
  "dId": "d_155",
  "pId": "5f4cb595cff47e0001b20882",
  "sId": "825",
  "paramName": "Utility_Air_Flow",
  "avg": 488270.454545455,
  "count": 220
 }
]

Comment: like this using the same formulae

Comment: THANK YOU AGAIN FOR THE EFFORT

Comment: See the query to calculate average of average of above data only https://mongoplayground.net/p/6VO6mTC6XrA